# PHP reload website once

Tags: javascript, php, header, reload

My Code looks like this.

fileA.php:

```
Item stored in DB: <?php echo $stored_item; ?> //displays the last selected item

<form action="fileB.php" method="post" type="submit">
       <input type="hidden" name="item" value="itemA">
   <button>Save</button></li>
</form>
<form action="fileB.php" method="post" type="submit">
       <input type="hidden" name="item" value="itemB">
   <button>Save</button></li>
</form>
```

fileB.php:

```
changeItem(); ... //Changes the entries in the database, works correctly
header('Location: fileA.php');
```

Now the entries have been changed in the database, but $stored_item shows the old entry, until i reload the page.

Now I would like to know, how I can refresh the fileA.php automatically after the `header('Location: fileA.php');` from fileB.php

I already tried things like:

```
echo '<script>window.location.reload();</script>';
header("Refresh:0");
```

But with them the website gets into a infinity-refreshing-loop, also if i use an if-Statement before:

```
if(isset($_POST)){ 
echo '<script>window.location.reload();</script>';
unset($_POST);}
```

Comment: Sorry but i'm unsure of what you need. You got a pag A which the user has open. Then he do something and it changes the value at the db and then you want to refresh the page? If the user is the same you can do it on ajax success function (As example)

Comment: you must use exit(); after header

Comment: thanks for the fast answers
@MarcoMura exactly, i want to refresh the page after changing the value in the db. And yes the user is the same, do you also know a php-solution or is it only realizeable with ajax?

Comment: If you want to refresh the data of all clients, you either need to pull the data in regular intervals or use a bidirectional connection type, like websockets.

Comment: If you already do an Ajax call then on success you can (as example) use window.location(url)

Comment: @MohamadAttat thanks, i have added it, but it still doesn't refresh the target-Location

Comment: @Markai I just want to refresh the page of the current user and an interval like Refresh:10, would disrupt the user expirience

Comment: @MarcoMura No, at the moment I'm not using Ajax, but if there is no other way, I'll have to.

Comment: @joh3 okay, if you just need to refresh the one client's data, then it doesn't matter and what i meant with "pull the data" was to just update the one part, where the data is displayed and not the whole page :)

Comment: @Markai hm, I know what you mean, but how can I just update/pull the data for a specific part in a .php-file? (Is it possible without Ajax?)

Comment: @joh3 No, will have to do that using html requests, because the php only get's executed server side when requested by the client unless you open a bidirectional communication and use a self invoking server script, but if you update the data from the server side it is called "pushing", if you request data from the client side it is called "pulling", which is much easier to realize

Comment: @Markai Okay, but the pulling is only executed, when the website reloads or am I wrong? So I need to refresh the site to get the new value and that is my actually problem.

Comment: @joh3 depends on your implementation. If you use setInterval with a function that just requests (through ajax) new data from the server, you won't have to update the whole website. But this should be used carefully, since it will create datatraffic and if you create a page for mobile end devices it can become a problem

Comment: @Markai Thanks for the answer. But ut actually is a website just for mobile devices.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with PHP:

```
header("Refresh:0");
```

It refreshes your current page, and if you need to redirect it to another page, use following:

```
header("Refresh:0; url=page2.php");
```

Comment: But if I use 
    header("Refresh:0");
and I want to stay on the same page, then it ends up in an infinite reload-loop

Answer (score 0):

you may use `header("Refresh:0")` if you need to refresh current page only.
If you want to refresh specific page you need to use `header("Refresh:0,url:$targeturl")` if you want to redirect on some other page ($targeturl). you may also use `header("Refresh:n");` for refreshing page after nth second